# SilverStripe custom grid field action button is added under the existing 3 dots/ more icon

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. In my project, I am creating a custom grid field action. I could create it. But there is still an issue in terms of UI. The custom grid field button is not added under the existing 3 dots/ more icon as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, my custom action button is added next to the 3 dots/ more icon.

Following is my custom grid field action class

```
class GridFieldCustomAction implements GridField_ColumnProvider, GridField_ActionProvider 
{

    public function augmentColumns($gridField, &$columns) 
    {
        if (!in_array('Actions', $columns)) {
            $columns[] = 'Actions';
        }
    }

    public function getColumnAttributes($gridField, $record, $columnName) 
    {
        return ['class' => 'grid-field__col-compact'];
    }

    public function getColumnMetadata($gridField, $columnName) 
    {
        if ($columnName === 'Actions') {
            return ['title' => ''];
        }
    }

    public function getColumnsHandled($gridField) 
    {
        return ['Actions'];
    }

    public function getColumnContent($gridField, $record, $columnName) 
    {
        if (!$record->canEdit()) {
            return;
        }

        $field = GridField_FormAction::create(
            $gridField,
            'CustomAction'.$record->ID,
            'Do Action',
            "docustomaction",
            ['RecordID' => $record->ID]
        );

        return $field->Field();
    }

    public function getActions($gridField) 
    {
        return ['docustomaction'];
    }

    public function handleAction(GridField $gridField, $actionName, $arguments, $data) 
    {
        if ($actionName !== 'docustomaction') {
            return;
        }
        // the rest of the code goes here
    }
}
```

This is how I added the action to the grid field.

```
$config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
$config->addComponent(new GridFieldCustomAction());
```

How can I put it under the existing ... icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridField actions are grouped into the "actions menu" when they implement [the `GridField_ActionMenuItem` interface](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4.5.0/src/Forms/GridField/GridField_ActionMenuItem.php).

[Loaded here](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4.5.0/src/Forms/GridField/GridField_ActionMenu.php#L96-L106):

```php
# GridField_ActionMenu.php
/**
 * Gets the list of items setup
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getItems($gridfield)
{
    $items = $gridfield->config->getComponentsByType(GridField_ActionMenuItem::class)->items;

    return $items;
}
```

You can add your custom action to it by implementing that interface.